# Javascript calculate time difference between timestamp within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I calculate the difference between each element within a timestamp array?

I want to create a new array with the diffence between each element of the array.

What I am trying to do is to push to the new array the difference calculated between the element index minus the previous element, in sequence...

The output in the console was almost a copy of the elements of the array, excluding the first element...

```
(46) [1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999]
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

```js
records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999];

function timeInteraction() {
      let timeArray = [records];
      let newArray = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
        var time = [timeArray[i].time];
        console.log(time);
        newArray.push(timeArray[i].time - timeArray[i].time[i - 1]);
      }
      console.log(newArray);
 }
timeInteraction();
```

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999]

let results = records.slice(1).map((e,i) => records[i+1] - records[i])

console.log(results)
```

Comment: The majority of the answers solved my issue but this one I prefer due to the scope of my code. Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

The elements in `timeArray` are simple numbers, they do not have a `time` property and it is definitely not an array.

You can remove the unnecessary square brackets from the subtraction too.

```js
const records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999];

function timeInteraction(timeArray) {
      let newArray = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < timeArray.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(timeArray[i] - timeArray[i-1]);
      }
      return newArray;
}

console.log(timeInteraction(records));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to create a new array with the differences:

```js
let records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999]

let results = records.map((record, index) => {
    return records[index+1] - record
});

// Remove last element
results.pop();

console.log(results);
```

Comment: The last element is `NaN`

Comment: I removed the last element to prevent NaN

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
function timeInteraction() {
    const nextRecords = records.slice(1);
    return nextRecords.map((next, prevId) => next - records[prevId]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And a reduce for completeness' sake

```js
const records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999]

const newArr = records.reduce((acc,cur,i) => {
  if (i>0 && i<records.length) acc.push(records[i] - records[i-1])
  return acc;
},[])  

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let records = [1612271438035, 1612271489789, 1612271498250, 1612271498756, 1612271499731, 1612271507831, 1612271508337, 1612271509048, 1612271511891, 1612271511895, 1612271512084, 1612271519936, 1612271520438, 1612271521713, 1612271525260, 1612271525264, 1612271527431, 1612271544137, 1612271544640, 1612271546389, 1612271551144, 1612271551646, 1612271553157, 1612271553163, 1612271557885, 1612271558028, 1612271558032, 1612271559399, 1612271559402, 1612271564461, 1612271564566, 1612271564570, 1612271564572, 1612271564577, 1612271567860, 1612271567863, 1612271568180, 1612271573603, 1612271573607, 1612271601243, 1612271601355, 1612271603883, 1612271604061, 1612271608817, 1612271608930, 1612271612965, 1612271613999];
let newArray = [];
records.forEach((ele,i)=>{
  if(i < records.length - 1)
    newArray.push(records[i+1]-ele);
});

console.log(newArray);
```